# segmentation fault from cudamalloc when allocating 3d pointer array to global memory

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to create a kernel that flattens a 3d pointer array to a 1d pointer array. To do so, I need to first allocate memory for the 3d pointer array in global memory. This is my approach to doing this.

```cs
#include <stdio.h>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

int main() {
    int image[3][3][3] = { //3 rows, columns, and 3 rgb values for each pixel
        {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
        {{10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}},
        {{19, 20, 21}, {22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27}}
    };

    const int IMAGE_ROW_COUNT = 3;
    const int IMAGE_COLUMN_COUNT = 3;
    const int ARRAY_BYTES = IMAGE_ROW_COUNT * IMAGE_COLUMN_COUNT * 3 * sizeof(float);

    float*** d_in2;
    float* d_out2;

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in2, IMAGE_ROW_COUNT * sizeof(float**)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out2, ARRAY_BYTES));

    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_ROW_COUNT; ++i) {
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in2[i], IMAGE_COLUMN_COUNT * sizeof(float*)));//issue
        for (int j = 0; j < IMAGE_COLUMN_COUNT; ++j) {
            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in2[i][j], 3 * sizeof(float)));
        }
    }
}
```

I have labeled where the segmentation fault occurs in the above code. Strangely there should also be some error message printed from [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api/14038590#14038590), but only segmentation fault is shown in the terminal.

Comment: It is illegal to access the memory  pointed to by  d_in2 and d_out2 in host code after you allocate them on the device